# why doesn't this javascript code work at all?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
  function help(n){

    document.write(n + '<br/>');
    if(n==10){ n=1;}
    n++;

    main(n);
 }

 function main(n){

  setTimeout('help(n)',500);

 }
```

I want it to print

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

and then again

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc

after 0.5 seconds

I want to do this by using the `setTimeout` method, but this approach doesn't work at all

My body element is like this

```
<body onload='main(1)'>
```

Can someone explain me why?

**Edit**: I changed the `foo` method to help. I made a mistake while editing my code in order to post this question.

Comment: Where is your `help` method called from?

Comment: It is good question-asking practice to be more descriptive instead of saying things "don't work at all"

Comment: What browser do you use? (I'm getting "'n' is not defined" error in Chrome, FF and IE9)

Comment: well it doesn't display anything on my browser, not even an error saying what's wrong I'm using firefox

Comment: of relevance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason you might get:

> attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope

in Firebug is due to the use of [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) after the page has loaded. This also [appears to be](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.platform/browse_thread/thread/10ff69b04b88e06f?pli=1) a new Firebug JS error.

Once it runs initially, you are writing to the document after you are allowed to. I tried using `document.open()` and `document.close()`, and adding both did not fix the issue.

There are better ways, though. You can use this to replace the `body` content:

```
document.body.innerHTML = n + '<br/>;
```

Or this to add to it:

```
document.body.innerHTML += n + '<br/>;
```

Or, this (what I would recommend):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = n + '<br/>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Note, do not use `setTimeout('help(n)',##)`, since that's `eval()`ing the code to call the function, which is bad practice. Also, avoid the second example above, since in some browsers you may experience performance issues due to the way that `.innerHTML` appends to a node. Hence, this is another bad practice to avoid.

Demonstration of the third method follows.

```
function help(n){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = n + '<br/>';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    if (n == 10) {
        n = 1;
    }

    n++;

    main(n);
}

function main(n){
    setTimeout(function(){
        help(n);
    }, 500);
}

main(5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/be6He/1

Comment: `document.write` in a queued function is a strange idea anyhow... Seems like writing into the contents of a specific DOM element is better (like your example).

Answer (score 1):

```
function main(n){  
    setTimeout(help,500,n);
}
```

or for full IE compatibility :

```
 function main(n){  
    setTimeout(function(){
        help(n);
    },500);
}
```

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp the third argument to `setTimeout` is the script language.

Comment: And that's why we don't trust w3schools. The additional params are not IE compatible though...

Answer (score 0):

Your `setTimeout` is calling a non-existent function, `foo()`.

Comment: sorry that was an error it's meant to be help I just changed it before posting the question and forgot to edit

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout takes a function reference, not a string.  Try something like:

```
function main(n)
{
  setTimeout(function () {
     help(n);
   }, 500);
}
```

**EDIT:**

`setTimeout` *can* take a string, but this function would not be run within the closure of `main` and `n` would be out of scope.  Plus, it's highly recommended to use a function reference, like the example above.

Comment: It can take a string - it shouldn't (it's an unnecessary `eval`), but it can.

Comment: Ah interesting, never knew it took a string as well.  So then in that case, yea `n` would be out of scope when it was called..

Answer (score 0):

`n` is no longer in scope when the help function executes. Your `main` should do something like:

```
function main(n) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        help(n);
    }, 500);
}
```